# Custom name and same color for some timeline operations (google charts timeline)

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am using google charts timeline to plot the data below using google charts timeline.

```
[{"id":59291,"idJob":2,"idOperation":3,"start":0,"end":3,"machine":1},    {"id":59292,"idJob":2,"idOperation":2,"start":3,"end":7,"machine":1},{"id":59293,"idJob":1,"idOperation":1,"start":7,"end":8,"machine":1},{"id":59294,"idJob":2,"idOperation":1,"start":8,"end":11,"machine":1},{"id":59295,"idJob":1,"idOperation":2,"start":0,"end":1,"machine":2},{"id":59296,"idJob":2,"idOperation":5,"start":7,"end":14,"machine":3},{"id":59297,"idJob":1,"idOperation":4,"start":1,"end":10,"machine":4},{"id":59298,"idJob":1,"idOperation":3,"start":8,"end":21,"machine":5},{"id":59299,"idJob":2,"idOperation":6,"start":3,"end":10,"machine":6},{"id":59300,"idJob":2,"idOperation":4,"start":11,"end":14,"machine":6},{"id":59301,"idJob":2,"idOperation":9,"start":10,"end":13,"machine":7},{"id":59302,"idJob":1,"idOperation":6,"start":13,"end":14,"machine":7},{"id":59303,"idJob":2,"idOperation":8,"start":14,"end":16,"machine":7},{"id":59304,"idJob":2,"idOperation":7,"start":16,"end":21,"machine":7},{"id":59305,"idJob":1,"idOperation":5,"start":21,"end":23,"machine":7},{"id":59306,"idJob":1,"idOperation":9,"start":14,"end":17,"machine":8},{"id":59307,"idJob":2,"idOperation":12,"start":18,"end":21,"machine":8},{"id":59308,"idJob":2,"idOperation":10,"start":21,"end":26,"machine":8},{"id":59309,"idJob":1,"idOperation":8,"start":26,"end":28,"machine":8},{"id":59310,"idJob":2,"idOperation":11,"start":18,"end":24,"machine":9},{"id":59311,"idJob":1,"idOperation":7,"start":24,"end":27,"machine":9},{"id":59312,"idJob":2,"idOperation":14,"start":21,"end":25,"machine":10},{"id":59313,"idJob":2,"idOperation":13,"start":26,"end":28,"machine":10},{"id":59314,"idJob":2,"idOperation":15,"start":28,"end":28,"machine":10},{"id":59315,"idJob":1,"idOperation":10,"start":28,"end":29,"machine":10}]
```

I have n jobs and n_i operations. The operation name should be "id_job,id_operation" e.g., the operation 1 of job 1 equals "1,1".

Google chart timeline defines the color of the operation based on the name of the operation, so for all operations with the same name it will choose the same color. What I am trying to do to is to create the chart exactly (same colors for the same job) as Fig. 1, however, with the text anchor of each operation with its respective name. If I try to define the respective name for each operation I end up with the graph shown in Fig. 2.

**Figure 1.**
[image: Figure 1]

**Figure 2.**
[image: Figure 2]

My javascript code.

```
function timelineChart() {
    $.ajax({
        url : "operations",
        dataType : "json",
        success : function(result) {
            google.charts.load('current', {
                'packages' : [ 'timeline' ]
            });
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
                drawChart2(result);
            });
        }
    });

    function drawChart2(result) {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Machine');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Job');
        data.addColumn('date', 'Start Date');
        data.addColumn('date', 'End Date');

        var dataArray = [];
        $.each(result, function(i, obj) {
            dataArray.push([ 'M' + obj.machine, getIdJob(obj) + "," + getIdOp(obj), new Date(obj.start * 1000), new Date(obj.end * 1000) ])
        });

        data.addRows(dataArray);

        var options = {
            timeline : {
                groupByRowLabel : true,
                showRowLabels : true,
                showBarLabels : true
            }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(document.getElementById('chart_timeline'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
}

function getIdJob(obj) {
    if (obj.idJob == 0) {
        return 'Unavailability';
    } else {
        return obj.idJob;
    }
}

function getIdOp(obj) {
    return obj.idOperation;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code bellow may work for your case. You can define a map of colors and then use it to draw your operations. You have to use DataView and remove the category before drawing.

```
function drawChart2(result) {
    var container = document.getElementById('chart_timeline');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    dataTable.addColumn({type : 'string',id : 'Machine'});
    dataTable.addColumn({type : 'string',id : 'Category'});
    dataTable.addColumn({type : 'string',id : 'ID'});
    dataTable.addColumn({type : 'date', id : 'Start'});
    dataTable.addColumn({type : 'date', id : 'End'});

    var colorMap = {};
    var dataArray = [];
    $.each(result, function(i, obj) {
        colorMap['Category' + getIdJob(obj)] = randomColor();
        dataArray.push(
        [ 'M' + obj.machine, 'Category'+getIdJob(obj), getIdJob(obj) + "," + getIdOp(obj), new Date(obj.start * 1000), new Date(obj.end * 1000) ])
    });

    dataTable.addRows(dataArray);

    var colors = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < dataTable.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
        colors.push(colorMap[dataTable.getValue(i, 1).toString()]);
    }

    var options = {
        timeline : {
            groupByRowLabel : true,
            showRowLabels : true,
            showBarLabels : true
        },
        colors : colors
    };
    console.log(dataTable);

    // use a DataView to hide the category column from the Timeline
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(dataTable);
    view.setColumns([ 0, 2, 3, 4 ]);

    chart.draw(view, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can define an extra column 'Category' and define a map with a color for each category. You can use the colors at the options and to avoid the error of extra column you can use DataView to hide the category column.

[image]